# What type of graph is this?

Tags: info-visualisation, graphs

[image]

What is this type of graph called? I find this graph across some website but I am unable to recall.

Following are the features of this graph:

1. Nodes are connected to a central node, indicating layers of information.
2. Clicking on a node gives information about that node.

Can someone provide some use cases and reference for this graph?

Answer (score 2):

The term is **[Force directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing)**.

[Here's an example](http://visualdataweb.de/webvowl/#) of an ontology, where the side panel displays selection (circle in red) details:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Hyperbolic Tree

Based on the info provided, this appears to be a hyperbolic tree.
Characteristics include:

- central node
- exponential node increases

[image: Sample hyperbolic tree visualization]

> A hyperbolic tree defines a graph drawing method inspired by
> hyperbolic geometry.
>
> Displaying hierarchical data as a tree suffers from visual clutter as
> the number of nodes per level can grow exponentially. For a simple
> binary tree, the maximum number of nodes at a level n is 2n, while the
> number of nodes for larger trees grows much more quickly.
>
> Drawing the tree as a node-link diagram thus requires exponential
> amounts of space to be displayed.

quote and example from [the data viz project](https://datavizproject.com/data-type/hyperbolic-tree/).

The interactivity of clicking to get information about a specific node is simply a good practice for any digital info visualization.

Answer (score 0):

I always knew this as **multinode graph** (in Graph Theory) or [**Network Diagram**](https://datavizcatalogue.com/methods/network_diagram.html) in DataViz